# What mythology sources were used by the author Rick Riordan?

Tags: rick-riordan

What books/sources he used for creation of his mythology book series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "*I’ve just finished work on the rough draft manuscript for Percy Jackson’s Greek Gods. For many years, I’ve wanted to retell the Greek myths. As a teacher, I always had trouble finding a good anthology of myths to use in my classroom. As much as I love Hamilton, D’Aulaires, Evslin, Graves and Greene, all these collections are a bit dated. I decided to try recasting the original stories by telling them in Percy Jackson’s voice. Rather than relying on the earlier anthologies listed above, I set them aside and went straight back to the sources – Homer, Hesiod, Nonnus, Apollodorus, Ovid et al.*"
>
> <sub><sup>[A update for August](https://rickriordan.com/2013/08/an-update-for-august/)</sup></sub>

And

> **JL:** *What kind of research did you have to do to get the mythology correct and still make everything appropriate for the twenty-first century?*
>
> **RIORDAN:** *I’ve been reading mythology for years, but I still brush up on the lesser-known facts using Web sites and reference books. One great Web site for mythology buffs is Theoi Greek Mythology ([www.theoi.com](http://www.theoi.com)), which profiles gods and other characters from Greek mythology.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Talking with Rick Riordan](https://www.ala.org/aboutala/offices/resources/riordan)</sup></sub>

And

> "*Greek mythology is studied extensively from grades 1-8, not to mention **the Iliad and the Odyssey** in the upper grades. English literature draws heavily on Greek mythology. It always has — from Chaucer all the way to modern novels. Percy Jackson is part of that tradition. I hope it makes kids want to read — that’s the most important thing!"*
>
> <sub><sup>[An Interview With Rick](https://rickriordan.com/about/an-interview-with-rick/)</sup></sub>

Comment: He reviewed The Song of Achilles; https://rickriordan.com/2012/08/ricks-reads-a-collection-from-the-blog/